# Build jenkins on Bitbucket pull request events

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm using [Post Webhooks for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215474/post-webhooks-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview) to automate triggering jenkins job on creation of pull request in Bitbucket Server.

Jenkins job has been created in order to **listen for all reposiotory branches changes** and is authenticated via ssh.

I use [BitBucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) on Jenkins side.

As it is said on plugin site I have created post hook in Bitbucket.

I have checked all pull options in order to test if it works.

The problem is that jenkins **reacts and builds project on**:

- pull request merged
- repository event: on push

and for events events like:

- pull request created
- pull request updated
- pull request declined
- pull request re-opened

it **does not work**, even though it is checked and work for two other options.

Does anyone have idea what can caouse this problem?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I would suggest using Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin in Jenkins. It will give you clear feedback. It can be used with the built in webhooks in Bitbucket Server or with the plugin you are using. https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin